# Error 500 in deploying Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, routes, kohana-3

I have been Googling all over for a solution or something that could direct me to a solution for deploying my Kohana 3.3 site but to no avail.

I am confused on on how make the routing work in Kohana, I left the default route in my bootstrap.php file intact. Here:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

I'm using a free web hosting and sub-domain and here's my URL: http://atosoft.neq3.com/. And that outputs "hello, world" just fine, with the route above.

But when I want to go to my admin page I get an ERROR 500 here: http://atosoft.neq3.com/admin. How do I set my route to make this work for all controllers?

I do not have sub directories in my Controllers and Models, just in my Views.

Here's my folder structure:

```
/Controller
   - Admin.php
   - Courses.php
   - Exams.php
   - Questions.php
   - Semester.php
   - User.php
   - Welcome.php
```

Controller/admin.php

```
class Controller_Admin extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'admin_template';

    public function action_index() {
        // User authentication
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();

        if(Auth::instance()->logged_in()) {
            // Display Dashboard here
            $dashboard = View::factory('admin/index');
            $this->template->user = $user;
            $this->template->content = $dashboard;
        } else {
            HTTP::redirect('user/login');
        }
    }
}
```

.htaccess

```
    # Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /atosoft.neq3.com/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
# RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system)/ - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
# RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT]
```

Comment: You need to find out what the generic "500" error actually means - it'll be in your log file.

Comment: I looked at Kohana's LOG folders but nothing in there that explains the problem, nothing that was logged on the current date.

Comment: Try your Apache/PHP logs `:)`

Comment: is it possible that the logs are stored somewhere else in the server?

Comment: ok, i tried it just now and the free service doesn't give me any access to the logs

Comment: I've never heard of a web host that doesn't give you access to logs - are you sure about that? They might be available in a control panel, or in your home folder via FTP.

Comment: well I do see a link that says Error Logs, under the Files pane, here's a link to what I see in the Error Logs http://flic.kr/p/gZ54XK

Comment: In that case, your framework may be returning a 500 HTTP response code without logging anything. It should offer a debug mode so you can see what the error actually is, on screen.

Comment: Created an account there, uploaded Kohana, and no problems. Did you change the .htaccess file? Post some more code. The admin controller, your .htaccess. The file structure, for example: I created a index.php in `/public_html/` containing only a `require '../kohana/index.php';` statement. The unzipped kohana (3.3.1) folder I put in the FTP's root. I then copied `/kohana/example.htaccess` to `/public_html/.htaccess`. Meaning the supplied .htaccess works just fine.

Comment: @Darsstar thank you very much for taking some time to look into it. I really appreciate that. I have updated my post with the full code of my HTACCESS file, also added code of my Admin Controller

Comment: I copied the contents of example.htaccess to public_html/.htaccess without any changes, now it gives me this error : Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL admin was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RewriteBase is wrong. This is from the Knowledge Base:

> Do you support search engine friendly URLs ?
>
> Yes, search engine friendly URLS are supported, but there is one
>   important thing you must know: We use virtual user directory paths, so
>   you can get error when trying to setup search engine friendly URLs or
>   trying to pass virtual directory names to PHP scripts. If can be fixed
>   very easy. Edit your .htaccess file and add this line at the top of
>   the file or before the first rewrite rule:
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> Note: if your script is installed on some directory, for example
>   /forum, you have to place RewriteBase /forum/ line to the .htaccess
>   file (.htaccess file must be also located in /forum directory)

Besides that [Kohana 3.3 also introduced support for PSR-0.](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#psr-0-support-fileclass-naming-conventions) So go through all your files in APPPATH/classes/ and rename them if necessary. For example: `APPATH/classes/Controller/admin.php` should be `APPPATH/classes/Controller/Admin.php`.

That should be it. If your kohana folder is currently inside the `/public_html` folder you might want to do something about that. It's a good idea to put as many files outside of the web root when possible.

Comment: yes, I have carefully followed the PSR-0 support, I replaced the .htaccess file in my root directory with EXACTLY the one in example.htaccess and now I am getting a Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL admin was not found on this server. Do I need to also change my base_url in BOOTSTRAP from my domain to / ?

Comment: OK, I am ALMOST THERE @Darsstar !! Now, it's not recognizing <?= url:base() ?> it says ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'url' not found